# How do I pass the second parameter to a function without passing the first?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have the following code:

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, N, V, F, L, T):
    self._Name = N
    self._VPs = V
    self._Fuel = F
    self._Lumber = L
    self._PiecesInSupply = T

def AddPiecesInSupply(self, T):
    modify = T+1
    modify.T
    return T
```

I have been given code and been asked to make changes. "self._PiecesInSupply = T" is a protected attribute. I have been asked to create a method to allow "self._PiecesInSupply = T" to be modified so I created the code:

```
def AddPiecesInSupply(self, T):
    modify = T+1
    modify.T
    return T
```

This is how I call Player.AddPiecesInSupply

```
Player.AddPiecesInSupply(0)
```

however the value 0 is being passed to the parameter self not T. Any ideas on how to pass the value 0 to T?

Thanks

Comment: Create an object instead of a function.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use the method as a static method. You should add the `@staticmethod` decorator and remove `self` from its signature. FWIW the function itself does not make much sense. It creates a new variable `modify`, dumps it and return the argument back

Comment: @DeepSpace also `modify.T` might not work like OP hopes it does. Actually, I have no idea what is the intent behind this line.

Comment: What do you expect `modify.T` to do? `modify` is a number, it has no `T` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar I want to take the value of T passed and add 1 to it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Katie010203 That's what `modify = T + 1` does. What do you think `modify.T` after that does?

Comment: Maybe what you want is `Player.modify = T + 1`?

Comment: I have re-worded the question, this might help. Thanks x

Comment: You repeat `modify.T` without explaining what you think it does or even what you are trying to make it do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, N, V, F, L, T):
    self._Name = N
    self._VPs = V
    self._Fuel = F
    self._Lumber = L
    self._PiecesInSupply = T

  def AddPiecesInSupply(self, T):
    self._PiecesInSupply += T
    return T

player = Player('name','VPs',1,2,3)
player.AddPiecesInSupply(0)
print(player._PiecesInSupply)
```